# How to Show Last Google Places Search Result Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, constants, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have a problem accessing the very last search result using [Google Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete).

### Expected Results

An alert with the very latest search result and any given parameter like `name` for example, when a button is clicked.

### Actual Results

I have used the given script from Googles [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) page, added a button and this code:

```
console.log(place.name);
$("#lb").click(function() {
   alert(place.name);
});
```

Right now, all search results are show when the button is clicked. One after another.

### JSFiddle

Please check my code at JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vloryan/1z2oscrj/

1. Search for at least two different places
2. Click the **Last Search Result Only**-Button
3. As mentioned, I get all results instead of the very last one only.

### Solution

I search and try in the meantime for 48h, without success. I would be very grateful for a solution to this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it something like this you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/rLu3yh6x/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you so much! Exactly! ThanksThanksThanks!

Answer (score 0):

here it is:
https://jsfiddle.net/nLuzahpj/1/

I create a variable at first, then I assign place.name to that variable in the function initMap().
And you do the alert outside this function.

```
var hey; //Outside the function, at the beggining of your code
hey = place.name; //In your function
  $("#lb").click(function() {   //Next to your function
   alert(hey);
 });
```